# ClassLoader, Class differences

Tags: java, class, classloader

I've read many forums about class loader and class, and that could be the mistake I did. I'm confused now.

1. When does ClassLoader get instantiated?
2. Read that "When a java source file is compiled to a binary class, compiler inserts a field into java class file. It is a `public` `static` `final` field named ‘class’ of type `java.lang.Class`". Is this true? Then how come we can access .class directly in our code without compiling?

Any other valid information that could help understand this better?

Comment: Darn, that's two questions.  I know the answer to #2 but I don't know the answer to #1.

Comment: You could still answer the second one though!

Answer (score 1):

1. `ClassLoader` is a container for your classes. So you manually create it when you need to load classes or JVM automatically creates it at start up to load your app. There is an hierarchy of class loaders, so it's a bit more complicated and [the article you quoted](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-class-loader/) well covers this topic.
2. I'm afraid, not. I think the author meant that it can be seen as a static field being injected into a class - and this really makes sense. I've just decompiled a class:

```
public class Role {
    public String role;
}
```

And it has no trace of that field in either bytes or this:

```
public class bear.core.Role {
  public java.lang.String role;

  public bear.core.Role();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

For your last qustion - modern IDEs just know that there is this `.class` field.

Answer (score 0):

```
When does ClassLoader get instantiated?
```

Class Loader get instantiated while loading the class file by the JVM after compilation before linking !